# Does the definition of a partial order require the definition of an equivalence relation?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Consider the set $S$ and a binary relation $R \subseteq S \times S$. $R$ is a partial order on $S$ if

1. $\forall s \in S, (s,s) \in R$ (reflexivity)
2. $\forall s_1,s_2 \in S, (s_1,s_2) \in R \wedge (s_2,s_1) \in R \implies s_1 = s_2$ (antisymmetry)
3. $\forall s_1,s_2,s_3 \in S, (s_1,s_2) \in R \wedge (s_2,s_3) \in R \implies (s_1,s_3) \in R$ (transitivity)

My question is about the antisymmetry property in (2). It seems to me that the statement "$s_1 = s_2$" can only be evaluated to be true or false if there already exists an equivalence relation $\sim \, \subset S \times S$. That is, $s_1 = s_2 \iff (s_1,s_2) \in \, \sim$. So, we cannot define a partial order on $S$ without first defining an equivalence relation on $S$ to check the antisymmetry property. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Let $S = \{\spadesuit,\heartsuit,\diamondsuit,\clubsuit\}$. How would one go about defining a partial order on $S$ without the existence of an equivalence relation on $S$?

Comment: @mhdadk $\bigl\{ (\heartsuit,\heartsuit),\, (\clubsuit,\clubsuit),\, (\diamondsuit,\diamondsuit),\, (\spadesuit,\spadesuit),\, (\heartsuit,\clubsuit),\, (\heartsuit,\diamondsuit),\, (\heartsuit,\spadesuit),\, (\diamondsuit,\spadesuit),\, (\clubsuit,\spadesuit) \bigr\}$ is a partial order on $S$, for example—no equivalence relation needed in its definition.

Comment: x = y can be evaluated as true or false using the Axiom of Extentionality. We check and see if they have the same elements. We don't need to go through an equivalence relation. Of course, unless you are considering = itself to be an equivalence relation. But, in Set Theory = is not a set ( and so not an equivalence relation)

Comment: @GregMartin isn't the equivalence relation $\{(\heartsuit,\heartsuit),\, (\clubsuit,\clubsuit),\, (\diamondsuit,\diamondsuit),\, (\spadesuit,\spadesuit)\}$ implicitly assumed to verify the antisymmetry property of your partial order?

Comment: @MichaelCarey "But, in Set Theory = is not a set" according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), the axiom of extensionality states that sets having the same elements are the same set. I'm not sure how this is relevant to my question, since in the statement "$s_1 = s_2$", neither $s_1$ nor $s_2$ are sets.

Comment: @mhdadk I honestly don't understand the point you are confused by. Different elements of a set are not equal, by definition. Even though equality is an example of an equivalence relation, we don't need to define an equivalence relation (nor even to define the notion of an equivalence relation) to work with equality. If you're unsure whether $\clubsuit \ne \diamondsuit$ in this example, that's an issue with the notation of this specific example, not a symptom of a need for an equivalence relation.

Comment: @GregMartin I see what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: @mhdadk If $s_1$ isn't a set then what is it? Whatever $s_1$ is you do need to define = for that respective object. You could define = as some equivalence relation; but in reality it's just a symbol and you can define it any way you want, within the contraints of whatever system you are working in.